Share thunderbird data between windows-kubuntu dual-boot
I have installed windows and kubuntu (24.04) as a dual boot with a shared NTFS partition between them. I installed Thunderbird on windows, and put all the data on said shared partition.
What I would like is to do the same thing with Kubuntu, so that regardless of whether or not I am using windows or linux, all changes reflect in both places, and I have one single record of my email.
I thought I could just point the Kubuntu Thunderbird at the same directory. However, every time I try to set the 'account settings' local directory in Kubuntu thunderbird, it stores my data in some undesired directory, '/run/user/1000/doc/....'. Why?
If I try to update the 'profiles.ini' file in /home/USER/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/ to point to the shared drive, it tells me that 'Thunderbird is already in use'.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

You will not like it, I suggest you can not run a Windows app and a Ubuntu app and share the same data.

If one updates to a different version, database changes may lock the other out. Happened a couple times in the past.

Thanks. Is there an alternative to the 'snap' version?

The conventional way to share email data across platforms is to use imap mail servers for all your accounts. The data is stored on the mail servers as opposed to your local drive as in the case of POP3 accounts. This resource explains in more detail This is not requires for gmail accounts which are handled differently.

Thanks Graham. I suspect that I will end up doing a full install on Linux and leaving only IMAP with no delete on windows. The downside is that I have old emails going back for decades from old defunct accounts in my local folders, and I wish I could keep it all available in one place.

I've not personally experimented with it in TB but isn't there an archiving facility you could use to effect this requirement?

I used to share both Firefox & Thunderbird in a NTFS partition back with XP. And shared both with multiple installs of Ubuntu/Kubuntu. But then FF starting giving version issues. So I just have one main working install & copy entire profile to other systems and periodically rsync to refresh. But I do not use snaps and find TB still works with shared partition. Expect soon will not be able to shared with TB.

Avoid snap applications whenever possible. They cause trouble.
Uninstall snap version of Thunderbird and install a regular .deb package.

Thunderbird, snap is the issue.
Go to Discover Software Center find Thunderbird, find the one that is snap and installed. On the bottom of page you will see Permissions, click and Enable Removable Media, Then see if you can do the changes you want.
If that is not possible you may need to uninstall the snap and install Thundebird classic. They are both available in Discover Software Center.

Or use the console-way:
sudo snap connect thunderbird:removable-media
